# Wrong status code in HttpResponse

Tags: java, rest, http, jax-rs, shiro

At first - I am pretty new to Java. I am working on an app that uses Shiro and I have defined a REST for logout. It has a redirect inside which gives me 302 Found Status Code while using dev tools in Chrome:

```
return Response.temporaryRedirect(redirectionAddress).build();
```

The problem is, I can't get this status using Postman or just by invoking it in a test:

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/shop/logout/);
HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(request);
```

After calling the rest I get only 200 OK code without 302 redirection. Prehaps it's the response when there is no session on the server side. In Postman I am using Basic Auth, but in the HttpGet there is no authorization because I am not sure how to do it. I tried adding a header, but it doesn't work also:

```
httpRequestBase.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);
```

Should I first invoke login rest and than logout? Is there any option to test the logout without login?

Comment: Postman does the redirect, you see only the result of the redirect, see https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/186.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache HttpClient does automatic redirect handling, see [HttpClient Tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e334):

> **1.7. Redirect handling**
>
> HttpClient handles all types of redirects automatically, except those explicitly prohibited by the HTTP specification as requiring user intervention. `See Other` (status code 303) redirects on `POST` and `PUT` requests are converted to GET requests as required by the HTTP specification.

but you can disable it, see [`HttpClientBuilder#disableRedirectHandling`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#disableRedirectHandling()):

> Disables automatic redirect handling.

Your modified code:

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/shop/logout/");
HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableRedirectHandling().build().execute(request);
```